# Did "supradictis" ever meant "aforementioned"?

Tags: meaning

In [1 Samuel 7:16](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=9&ch=7&l=16-#x) we read:

> *et ibat per singulos annos circuiens Bethel et Galgala et Masphath, et judicabat Israelem in **supradictis** locis.*

The English translation (see link) of *supradictis* is (the rather old fashion) "aforesaid", or "aforementioned". **Is this meaning attested in Latin?** [Wictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/superdictus#Latin) (which indicates *supradictus* to be an alternative form of *superdictus*) does not think so. 
There is no entry on L&S for *supra/superdictus*. The only reference to it is found in the entry for [*supra*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=supra&highlight=supradictus), which states:

> Compounds formed with supra are extremely rare. In late Lat. supradictus, suprafatus, suprafundo, suprajacio, supranatans, suprasedeo, etc., are found, but here supra is properly written separately as an adv.; only suprascando (v. h. v.), on account of its signif., is to be written as one word.

Interestingly, aforementioned = afore + mentioned, and afore comes from OE/ME fore, which comes from PIE *per, which also derived in the Latin *per*. Given that *supradictis* is synonymous with *superdictis*, the two words seems to be indeed indirectly related.